# Span tag space issue

Tags: html

Scenario 1:

```html
<html>
<span>200</span> <span>9</span>
</html>
```

Outputs 2009

Scenario 2 :

```html
<html>
<span>200</span>
<span>9</span>
</html>
```

Outputs : 200 9  (space between 200 9)

is there way to over come this issue. HTML for scenario 2 is being generated from .net XSL Transformation.

Comment: <span>200</span> <span>9</span> outputs "200 9" in Chrome and IE, and pretty sure it does in Firefox as well.

Comment: Your scenario 1 shows as `200 9` in my firefox.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to retain the line breaks but don't want visible whitespace when viewing the document, you can wrap the line breaks in comments.

```
<html>
   <span>200</span><!--
--><span>9</span>
</html>
```

It looks a bit messy, but when there are several nesting levels in the code, it's a far easier solution than removing the line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a difference between the two: both are rendered with a space between 200 and 9, as expected ( [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/U8XUz/3/) ).

What browser are you using? Is it the same with other browsers?

You have to eliminate the whitespace between the `</span>` and `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove whitespaces from string before you output it as HTML?!